# success_url in UpdateView, based on passed value

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

How can I set `success_url` based on a parameter?
I really want to go back to where I came from, not some static place.  In pseudo code:

```
url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/(?P<category>\d+)',
    UpdateView.as_view(model=Entry, 
                       template_name='generic_form_popup.html',
                       success_url='/category/%(category)')),
```

Which would mean: edit entry `pk` and then return to 'category'.  Here an entry can be part of multiple categories.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Create a class `MyUpdateView` inheritted from `UpdateView` and override `get_success_url` method:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        pass #return the appropriate success url
```

Also i like to pass such parameters like template_name and model inside of inheritted class view, but not in `.as_view()` in urls.py

Comment: This way `get_success_url` will point to a url like `/items/1/None` which does not exist.

Answer (score 36):

Had the same issue. Was able to get the paramater from self.kwargs as Dima mentioned:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        if 'slug' in self.kwargs:
            slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        else:
            slug = 'demo'
        return reverse('app_upload', kwargs={'pk': self._id, 'slug': slug})
```

Comment: This was useful for me - though I needed to make sure that the slug started with "/", otherwise I was getting urls like "/formpage/successurl/successurl/successurl/" that kept adding to the end, instead of the beginning.

Comment: @JayCrossler - I think that is due to relative addresses versus absolute addresses. The leading slash implies that the url starts there. Without a slash, it gets appended to the previous url, Like unix paths with the ls command.

Comment: Could further simplify using .get(): slug = self.kwargs.get('slug', 'demo')

Comment: I'm in *Django 2.2.5* - `'pk': self._id` need to change into `'pk': self.object.id`

Answer (score 8):

I found a way which is useful and very simple. Check it out.

```
class EmployerUpdateView(UpdateView):
        model = Employer
        #other stuff.... to be specified

        def get_success_url(self):
           pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
           return reverse("view-employer", kwargs={"pk": pk})
```

Comment: Could you explain what `view-employer` is in this context?

Comment: ```view-empployer``` is the name of the EmployerDetailView in ```urlpatterns``` list. Like so ```path("view-employer/<pk>/", EmployerDetailView.as_view(), name="view-employer")```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it still produces and error: "Reverse for 'view-employer' not found. 'view-employer' is not a valid view function or pattern name. I just opened a question with my particular issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262282/how-to-redirect-an-updateview-upon-success

Comment: Ok I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Define `get_absolute_url(self)` on your model. Example

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    # etc ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('poll', args=[self.slug])
```

If your `PollUpdateView(UpdateView)` loads an instance of that model as `object`, it will by default look for a `get_absolute_url()` method to figure out where to redirect to after the `POST`. Then

```
url(r'^polls/(?P<slug>\w+)/, UpdateView.as_view(
    model=Poll, template_name='generic_form_popup.html'),
```

should do.

Comment: And in case of a CreateView, since the instance does not exist yet, just create a form_valid function like:
    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.profile_id = self.request.user.id
        obj.save()
        self.success_url = self.model.get_absolute_url(obj)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a 'next' parameter to your form (template) and catch it in your view. It's common practice to achieve redirecting this way.