# Providing parameters when reverse_lazy-ing a success_url redirect

Tags: django, lazy-evaluation, django-urls

TLDR: I want to be able to provide `slug` in `reverse_lazy('view', kwargs={'slug':'my_page'})` like this: `reverse_lazy('view').apply(kwargs={'slug':'my_page'})`, after creating the lazy object.

---

I have the following url pattern that includes a slug to identify a page model instance:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>'+settings.SLUG_PATTERN+')/$', views.MyView.as_view(), name='view'),
```

I have another view for editing the page:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>'+settings.SLUG_PATTERN+')/_edit/$',
    views.MyEditView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('view')), name='edit'),
```

Note the addition of `success_url` so that when I submit the form with the new content I'm redirected to the now-edited page. In case I ever change my `view` url pattern I don't have to worry about updating the redirect for my `edit` url.

After the form is validated and saved, the view grabs the success url to be used  in a `HttpResponseRedirect`. However just the name 'view' isn't enough to identify the URL. I also need to know the slug name which is stored in my page model's `slug` field.

A similar question is here: [success_url in UpdateView, based on passed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027996/success-url-in-updateview-based-on-passed-value)

The answers suggest writing a custom `get_success_url` for *every* view, but there must be better approaches.

In the generic views in django's edit.py there's this:

```
url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
```

If `success_url` were given as a hard coded URL but with a slug identifier such as `'{slug}/'` this would replace it with the `slug` field in my model. That's very close to what I want, but I don't want to hard code my URL. This brings me to my question:

**How can I pass in parameters to a `reverse_lazy` object?** I would use this in my base view's `get_success_url` with `self.object.__dict__` and it'd just work everywhere.

Moreover if my slug string was stored on separate Slug model I might want the success URL to be `'{slug.name}/'`. With the above approach I could supply a mapping between the URL parameters and model attributes:

```
redirect_model_mapping = {'slug': '{slug.name}'}
...
def get_success_url(self):
    url = self.success_url
    if is_a_lazy_redirect(url):
        url = url.somehow_apply_parameters(redirect_model_mapping)
    return url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
```

I would like `somehow_apply_parameters` to be equivalent to originally calling `reverse_lazy('blog:view', kwargs=redirect_model_mapping)`. However I don't think this should be in `urls.py` because it shouldn't have to know about the mapping.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack, but does what I want...

```
class MyView(FormMixin, ...):

    #this is actually set on child classes
    redirect_model_mapping = {'slug':'{slug.name}'}

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = self.success_url
        if url is not None:
            if hasattr(self.success_url, '_proxy____kw'):
                url_parameters = dict((k, v.format(**self.object.__dict__)) for k, v in six.iteritems(self.redirect_model_mapping))
                url._proxy____kw = {'kwargs': url_parameters}
                url = force_text(url)
            else:
                url = url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("No URL to redirect to.")
        return url
```

It replaces the `kwards` parameter normally passed to `reverse_lazy` but after it actually has the values it needs. As `reverse_lazy` also requires the string to match the regex, I had to make the mapping between url parameters and the values in the models first.

I'd quite like an approach that doesn't need to write to `_proxy____kw`.