# Collect data from a class based form UpdateView django for use in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form based on my model "configuration" :

models.py

```
class configuration(models.Model):
    Num_ordre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Composant = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Designation = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Qte_servie = models.IntegerField()
    Qte_a_servir = models.IntegerField()
    Lot = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Categorie  = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Famille = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

From this model I create a form with the UpdateView function : 
views.py

```
class ComposantUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = configuration
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'accueil/exploitation/update_composant.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cahier', args=('OFTSP1611000853',))`
```

My problem is that the success_url gets an argument I have entered manually : OFTSP1611000853 which corresponds to configuration.Num_ordre for pk=1.

Instead of 'OFTSP1611000853' I want to put the data written by the user in the corresponding field in the form.

How can I collect this value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [success\_url in UpdateView, based on passed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027996/success-url-in-updateview-based-on-passed-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `get_success_url`. And inside that get the user data and then return it, Something like this:

```
def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):         
    return reverse_lazy('cahier', kwargs={'pk': self.request.data.get('cahier_id')})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with self.request.POST.get('numero_ordre') I didn't know the method self.request was a thing !

Comment: the `self.request` is available inside almost any method of your view. Its commonly used with `self.request.POST` or `self.request.GET`. o/