# How to redirect an UpdateView upon success?

Tags: django, django-views

I created a small Django application to manage data that fits a simple a model. For now I only need two views: one to list all records and another to edit a record with a generic form. Everything functions as expected, except the redirection from the edit view upon a successful update. In `urls.py` are the following contents:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'reqs'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ReqUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
]
```

In `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Requirement


class RequirementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ['name', 'priority', 'source' , 'rationale']
```

And the templeate `requirement_form.html`:

```
<h1>{{ requirement.id }} - {{ requirement.name }}</h1>

<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <tr><td></td><td><button type="submit">Save</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
    
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<br><br>
<a href="{% url 'reqs:index' %}">Back to list</a>
```

Finally `views.py`, on a first attempt to redirect the update to the list:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Requirement
from .forms import RequirementForm

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'reqs/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'requirements_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Requirement.objects.order_by('subject')

class ReqUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Requirement
    form_class = RequirementForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('/')
```

With this formulation the *Save* button produces this error:

> Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I also tried an empty string as argument to `reverse_lazy`, as well as the path name `index`, but a similar error message is produced.

On a second attempt I tried to redirect to the same page, [redefining the `get_success_url` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786050/2066215) to do nothing:

```
class ReqUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Requirement
    form_class = RequirementForm
    context_object_name = 'requirement_update'
    def get_success_url(self):
        pass #return the appropriate success url
```

This returns a 404 error trying to redirect the browser to `/reqs/1/None`.

A third attempt to redirect to the form with the same record:

```
class ReqUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Requirement
    form_class = RequirementForm
    context_object_name = 'requirement_update'
    def get_success_url(self):
           pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
           return reverse("update", kwargs={"pk": pk})
```

Which complains about not finding the view:

> Reverse for 'update' not found. 'update' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

How can I redirect success to a valid URL? It can either be the items list or the item update view, as long as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse / reverse_lazy are used to get the url using view name or pattern name. If you want to use a url directly just write:

```
success_url = '/'
```

For the case of `return reverse("update", kwargs={"pk": pk})` not working since you set `app_name = 'reqs'` you should be using `return reverse("reqs:update", kwargs={"pk": pk})` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are few misconception that you did

- reverse parameter should be as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/)

> ```
>  URL pattern name or the callable view object
> ```

- You have set namespace but you are not reversing with namespace as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

So in your case

```
def get_success_url(self):
       pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
       return reverse("reqs:update", kwargs={"pk": pk})
```