# How can I redirect the user's own 'post-detail' URL in the UpdateView class?

Tags: python, django

Consider:

#### File **views.py**

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin , UpdateView):
    model =  Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_create.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content' ]
    # After POST, request the URL
    success_url = 'post-detail'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        Post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == Post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

This 'success_url' doesn't work.

I need the user, after updating their own post, to redirect back to their post details page:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailview.as_view(), name='post-detail'
```

And I need one more help - how can I send success messages after the update?

#### File *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailview,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    about
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailview.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/create', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
]
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027996/success-url-in-updateview-based-on-passed-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the URL namespace (`post-detail`), not the URL into the *success_url* as per the [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) document:

*[success_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url)*

We should assign the URL and that you can do by using either `reverse` or `reverse_lazy`.

As per your `url.py`, you want to redirect the details page on a specific user post. For that, you should override the *get_success_url* method, like Bichanna mentioned in her post.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    object_id = self.kwargs[self.pk_url_kwarg]
    return reverse_lazy('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': object_id})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of doing it right:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin , UpdateView):
        model =  Post
        template_name = 'blog/post_create.html'
        fields = ['title', 'content' ]
        # after post request url
        # success_url = 'post-detail' comment this line
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse("post-detail", args=[pk]) # you can replace pk
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69826094/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Though that may not happen anytime soon: [*"This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends on Mar 16 '22 at 22:45."*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15256253/bichanna)